# converting different timezones to a unique time zone using hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have data in this way

```
'           date            |  Col 1
 ----------------------------------------
 2014-07-07 00:02:15.089-07 |   10
 2014-07-07 00:08:15.069-08 |   20
 2014-07-10 00:04:17.079-09 |   40
 2014-07-08 00:07:15.089-06 |   30
```

The 07/08/09/06 at the end of the date string represents the time zone. I am trying to get a avg of column. But first i need to convert all the different time zones in to a unique time zone. I need to convert all the date strings to UTC and then do an average of col 1 for different days or hours. I thought of using substrings, but doesn't help. Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: Is the date field a varchar then?

Comment: I am considering the date field as a string.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use UDF (User defined functions) for the purpose. 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Comment: Please include relevant information from a link in the answer itself. As it stands now this is more of a comment then an answer. Links die, become outdated, change etc. Perhaps you can include an example of how to use UDF to solve the problem posed in the question?